# Why does code written in Ruby 2.1 have to be parsable by Ruby 2.0 interpreter?

Tags: ruby, literals, ruby-2.0, string-literals, ruby-2.1

In Ruby Core, a new literal notation `"foo"f` for frozen strings have been proposed for Ruby 2.1, but [now](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8992) people are concerned that code written in such syntax would not be parsable by Ruby 2.0. Why is that an issue? Hasn't Ruby tried to be only backward compatible? That is, if code written in Ruby 2.0 can be parsed by Ruby 2.1 interpreter, isn't that enough? Why does code written in Ruby 2.1 have to be parsable by Ruby 2.0 interpreter?

Comment: @muistooshort: First off: That syntax is illegal in 2.0, therefore it's not a breaking change. All code written for 2.0 will still work in 2.1. Secondly, even if it *were* a breaking change, a new major release like 2.1 is *exactly* when it *should* happen.

Comment: @muistooshort: I think you are confused about the Ruby versioning policy. Ruby has a 4-part version number: W.X.Y-pZ. Z is a patch release, only bugfixes are allowed. Y is a minor release, backwards-compatible new features are allowed. X is a major release, backwards-compatibility may be broken. W is an epochal release, reserved for monumental milestones in the history of the Ruby language: 0.x → 1.x was the first production-ready release, 1.x → 2.x was the 20th anniversary of Ruby. 2.0 → 2.1 is a major release, ergo, breaking changes are allowed … but this isn't even a breaking change!

Comment: @muistooshort: There *is no* code which could possibly be broken by this change because that syntax is *illegal*. Period. So, even if this *were* a minor release (which it isn't, 2.0.1 would be a minor release), it would *still* be okay, because it's *not* a breaking change, since there is no code to break.

Answer (score 1):

That's a very good question. I have followed the core ML for a while and I believe the main concern here is that the new frozen literal syntax is a syntax change, not only a feature change.

Let me expand the answer a little bit. First of all, let's remember that we are talking about a minor version change, that is not supposed to break compatibility with previous code. Indeed, you may argue that *in fact*, this is not going to happen at all. Ruby 2.0 code will just work fine in Ruby 2.1, but not the opposite.

You also mentioned that is implicit that a new version will possibly include features not available in the previous version. But I believe here's exactly where the concerns are starting.

The new syntax is introducing not only a feature change but also a syntax change. It means that if you try to feed Ruby 2.0 parser with Ruby 2.1 code, it will possibly fail. And this may not be a good idea, for all the reasons we already know (compatibility, migration, maintenance, etc).

And this is quite different than when you create a new method in Ruby 2.1 that is not available to Ruby 2.0. In this case, it's true that 2.1 will have more features than 2.0, but if you feed the previous interpreter with the same code base, it will not complain. You didn't change the language syntax, you just enriched the core library. And, in this case, it's very easy to make your 2.0 code more similar to 2.1: just implement the missing methods.

This is not possible with a syntax change because you will need to reimplement the parser.

If you look at the Ruby changes under this point of you, you will see that a very few syntax changes were introduced between minor versions.

Changes like the stubby lambda, keyword arguments, new hash notation, they were all introduced with a major bump.

Generally speaking, syntax level changes may cause more maintenance issues compared to feature level changes. This is my interpretation of the reason behind the new frozen literal syntax and the reason why they ended up using [`.freeze` instead of the new syntax](http://tmm1.net/ruby21-fstrings/). `freeze` already exists in previous Ruby version, but even if they would come with a completely new method, methods are not evaluated at parse time and they can be easily backported.

Answer (score 0):

The answers I have in mind are:

- easier migration from ruby 2.0 to 2.1
- share code between ruby version
- people seem to find the f-suffix ugly/confusing

### Migration

When the syntax is parse-able by both ruby versions, it is one task less on the list to migrate from 2.0 to 2.1. Existing code may benefit from better frozen string handling without any changes.

### Shared code between ruby versions

With a similar syntax, you can write ruby code (especially libraries), which work with multiple ruby version (2.0 and 2.1). This gives library developers a greater audience (and less versions to maintain for different ruby versions). The library user, however, has an easier time migrating from ruby 2.0 to 2.1. Still the ruby 2.1 version can benefit from better frozen string handling.

### Personal taste

Reading through the ruby bug tracker, I see that some people seem to find the new syntax ugly/confusing. Here are some examples:

- ["[not using the f-suffix] looks like Ruby"](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8992)
- ["The [f-suffix] notation is ugly."](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8976)
- ["it is confusing about the character 'f'. For example, it remind 'Float'"](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8579#note-18)
- ["I personally dislike prefix/suffix forms, they feel like u'str' in python"](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8992#note-5)
- ["it looks very strange"](http://rkh.im/ruby-2.1) (ok, this one is not from the tracker)

There are other people who like the new syntax. Well, this is subjective, but we are wondering why people complain, so it is a point :)

Comment: Your argument applies to any type of newly added feature, which there are plenty of between 2.0 and 2.1. I don't think it explains why frozen string literal became an issue.

Comment: Sure. However, this is a new feature with two possible implementations - one of them compatible, the other not. So we have a choice. If there is a choice, there are discussions. Plus, headius mentions other reasons (apart, from 2.0 compatibility) in his post (but you haven't asked about them).